# JASIG CAS with JBOSS AS 7 application

Tags: jboss7.x, cas

Is there any example how to integrate JASIG CAS with my JBOSS AS 7 application?
So what I have
web.xml

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All resources</web-resource-name>
            <description>Protects all resources</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
              org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.Saml11AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
              <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>service</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/JAdaptiv/default.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
              <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>serverName</param-name>
              <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>redirectAfterValidation</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
              <param-name>tolerance</param-name>
              <param-value>1000</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Assertion Thread Local Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>CasSecurityDomain</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name>
    </valve>  
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="CasSecurityDomain">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jasig.cas.client.jaas.CasLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="ticketValidatorClass" value="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator"/>
                            <module-option name="casServerUrlPrefix" value="https://localhost:8443/cas"/>
                            <module-option name="tolerance" value="20000"/>
                            <module-option name="defaultRoles" value="user"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeNames" value="memberOf,eduPersonAffiliation,authorities"/>
                            <module-option name="principalGroupName" value="CallerPrincipal"/>
                            <module-option name="roleGroupName" value="Roles"/>
                            <module-option name="cacheAssertions" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="cacheTimeout" value="480"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

When i'm trying to get rest

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/bpm/processdefinitions
```

I got error message.
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 403 - JBWEB000015: Access to the requested resource has been denied

Whats wrong?

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same problem.